# $f(x) \equiv 1$ mod $(x-1)$ and $f(x) \equiv 0$ mod $(x-3)$ then is there any $f(x)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Let $S$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients satisfying

$f(x) \equiv 1$ mod $(x-1)$

$f(x) \equiv 0$ mod $(x-3)$

Which of the following statements are true?

a) $S$ is empty .

b) $S$ is  a singleton.

c)$S$ is  a finite non-empty set.

d) $S$ is  countably infinite.

My Try: I took $x =5$ then $f(5) \equiv 1$ mod $4$ and $f(5) \equiv 0$ mod $2$ . Which is impossible so $S$ is empty.

Am I correct? Is there any formal way to solve this?

Comment: Hint: for all polynomials $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and all integers $n$ we have
$$f(x)\equiv f(n)\pmod{x-n}.$$

Comment: Mind you, your method is ok. I may be a bit wooden in my thinking, but I would have used the hint to show that we must have $f(1)=1$ and $f(3)=0$. Then observe that because $1\equiv3\pmod 2$ we must also have $f(1)\equiv f(3)\pmod2$. But yours is ok.

Comment: By polynomial division algorithm each polynomial has a **unique** constant as a remainder when divided by a monic **linear** polynomial.

Comment: @cmi: Your proof is basically correct. The hints by mfl show how to get a formal justification. Assuming that such an $f$ exists, $f$ must satisfy the identity $f(x)-1=a(x)(x-1)$, for some polynomial $a(x)$ with integer coefficients, and must also satisfy the identity $f(x)= b(x)(x-3)$, for some polynomial $b(x)$ with integer coefficients. Then, as in your argument, $f(5)-1=4a(5)$, so $f(5)$ is odd, but also, $f(5)=2b(5)$, so $f(5)$ is even. It follows that there is no such $f$. Instead of considering $f(5)$, you can use any odd input, for example $f(1)$, and you get the same contradiction.

Comment: A good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let we have a general polynomial form as following$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_dx^d$$We know that for some polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ $$f(x)=1+(x-1)a(x)=b(x)(x-3)$$therefore $$f(1)=1\\f(3)=0$$ which leads to $$(1)\quad a_0+a_1+\cdots +a_d=1\\(2)\quad a_0+3a_1+\cdots +3^da_d=0$$by subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ we obtain $$2a_1+8a_2+\cdots +(3^d-1)a_d=-1$$which is impossible since the LHS is even and the RHS is odd, so ***such a polynomial doesn't exist***

Comment: How the last equation is impossible?@Mostafa Ayaz

Comment: The LHS is even and the RHS is odd...

Answer (score 4):

The second condition basically says that $3$ is a root. 
But then substitute $x=3$ into the first condition: $0=f(3)\equiv 1 \pmod 2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)\equiv f(n)\mod x-n$, the second condition says $f(3)=0$ and $f(x)=(x-3)g(x)$ for some $g(x)\in\mathbf Z[x]$. But then $\;f(1)=-2g(1)$ is even, contrary to the first condition $f(1)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$f(x)\equiv 1\bmod{(x-1)}\iff \exists a(x)|f(x)=(x-1)a(x)+1.$$

$$f(x)\equiv 0\bmod{(x-3)}\iff \exists b(x)|f(x)=(x-3)b(x).$$

So, if $f$ exists then it must be

$$(x-1)a(x)+1=(x-3)b(x).$$ We have for $x=1:$

$$1=-2b(1)\implies b(1)=-\dfrac 12,$$ which is not possible, since $b(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficientes and $1\in\mathbb{Z}$. (Note taht in a similar way we have $a(3)=-\frac12$.) Thus we conclude that there is no a polynomial with integer coefficients satisfying the given conditions.

As it was said in comments your proof is essentially correct. If $f$ exists then it must be

$$f(5)=4a(5)+1\equiv 1\bmod{4}$$ and $$f(5)=2b(5)\equiv 0\bmod{2}.$$ Since both congruences can't hold together you can conclude that the polynomial doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you please tell me if my way was correct or wrong? and can you please elaborate I am too  naïve in this field to get your hint.@mfl

Comment: You said "Thus we conclude that $a(x),b(x)$ don't exist."..Is the line correct? As we will get infinite number $a(x)$ but we will not get any polynomial $b(x)$ which satisfies that condition @mfl

Comment: Maybe the sentence is not completely clear. Anyway, $a(x)$ doesn't exist because $(x-1)a(x)+1=(x-3)b(x)\implies a(3)=-\dfrac 12.$ I have modified the sentence to make the answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is short and correct. Indeed:
$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}f(x)\equiv 1\bmod{(x-1)}\\ f(x)\equiv 0\bmod{(x-3)}\end{cases} &\iff
\begin{cases}f(x)=(x-1)a(x)+1\\ f(x)=(x-3)b(x) \end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}f(5)\equiv 1\bmod{4}\\f(5)\equiv 0\bmod{2}\end{cases} &\iff\begin{cases} f(5)=4a(5)+1\\ f(5)=2b(5) \end{cases}\\
0\equiv 1\bmod 2&\iff 0=2(2a(5)-b(5))+1 \Rightarrow \\
\emptyset &\iff \emptyset
\end{align}$$